# Iterative search using Prolog

Tags: search, prolog, iteration

search.pl

```
solve(P) :-
      start(Start),
      search(Start,[Start],Q),
      reverse(Q,P).

search(S,P,P) :- goal(S), !.         /* done                  */
search(S,Visited,P) :-
     next_state(S,Nxt),              /* generate next state   */
     safe_state(Nxt),                /* check safety          */
     no_loop(Nxt,Visited),           /* check for loop        */
     search(Nxt,[Nxt|Visited],P).    /* continue searching... */

no_loop(Nxt,Visited) :-
      \+member(Nxt,Visited).
```

queen.pl

```
start([]).
goal(S) :- length(S,8).

next_state(S,[C|S]) :- member(C,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]),notmember(C,S).
safe_state([C|S]) :- length(S,L),
                     Sum is C+L+1, Diff is C-L-1,
                     safe_state(S,Sum,Diff).


safe_state([],_,_) :- !.
safe_state([F|R],Sm,Df) :- length(R,L),
                           X is F+L+1,
                           X \= Sm,
                           Y is F-L-1,
                           Y \= Df,
                           safe_state(R,Sm,Df).
```

how to run this ??? im not getting how to work on this code .
it is for iterative search using prolog.
concept of search and how it can be implemented in prolog through graph method. Implementation of basic search for finding next state is done in this experiment.

Comment: How much Prolog do you know? Did you copy this code from somewhere and need an explanation? This isn't a fundamental tutorial site, so your question may not be a good fit here. What have you tried?

Comment: im newbie .yes i did copy it. i just want to know how to make it work.

Comment: Just run the query: `solve(P)` and it will give you solutions for `P`. If you look through the code, you can see that it's the top-most call. Also, it's called `solve` which is another hint.

Comment: this is the error
ERROR: Undefined procedure: start/1
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] start(_928)
ERROR:    [8] solve(_952) at c:/users/lalit/documents/prolog/search.pl:2
ERROR:    [7] <user>
   Exception: (9) start(_1010) ?

Comment: In the code above you clearly have `start/1` defined so you haven't loaded all of this code if you get `start/1` undefined, in particular, `queen.pl` is evidently not loaded. It's very unclear what you're doing here. You're showing source for two `pl` modules, but I don't know how you loaded it and if you did that correctly. You need to make  sure you load both `pl` files.

Comment: how to load both files at a time?

Comment: You can load them one after another. For example, enter `[file1].` followed by `[file2].` where `file1.pl` and `file2.pl` are your file name.

Comment: this error is occured after i called "solve(P)."
ERROR: Undefined procedure: not_member/2
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [11] not_member(1,[])
ERROR:   [10] next_state([],[1]) at c:/users/lalit/documents/prolog/queen.pl:4
ERROR:    [9] search([],[[]],_7180) at c:/users/lalit/documents/prolog/search.pl:8
ERROR:    [8] solve(_7210) at c:/users/lalit/documents/prolog/search.pl:3
ERROR:    [7] <user>

Comment: Just listen to the error message. `Undefined procedure: not_member/2` means Prolog didn't find a definition in your code for `not_member/2`. It's not a built-in Prolog predicate. Where is your definition? Also, it doesn't make sense since the code you show above calls `notmember/2` (also not defined anywhere by the way).

Comment: this is the code that i have. if u can suggest something better then please go for it.

Comment: I would suggest writing the missing predicates, or find another approach that doesn't use the  missing predicates.

Comment: Okay thank you. But if you can suggest me any other code then please do it.